# Origin of the Christoffel symbol

Tags: differential-geometry

I am interested in the Christoffel symbol. So I found Christoffel's 1869 paper and *The Road to Reality* by Roger Penrose. These days, the Christoffel symbol has been established as a covariant derivative, but Christoffel did not know the concept of covariant derivative and parallel transport.

So, I wondered what concept Christoffel used to create the Christoffel symbol at the time.

When I read the book *The Road to Reality*, I think that Lie algebra was use. What exactly is the concept behind the Christoffel symbol?

Comment: Don't they show up naturally when you compute derivatives in an arbitrary coordinate system with a non-constant metric?

Comment: Consider reading chapters IV and V of Volume 2 of Spivak's "Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry": Among other things, he discusses the origin of Christoffel symbols.

Comment: Pretty sure it would be from gauss. By the way, I finished a large portion of that book already, so if you want to discuss it, feel free to send me a message on the stackexchange chat.